# Jmeter can't download large file with http raw request or http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

**target:**

- simulator 10 users download the file from the server
- the file size   more than 300M
- use HTTP request sampler to download file on the    Nginx server with
  bean shell script.

**result:**

- success 2/10
- jmeter log :java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**configure in jmeter.bat:**

- set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m
- set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m   -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m

**please help, thanks.**

**bean shell script**

```
   import java.io.*;

   byte[] result=prev.getResponseData();
   String file_name="d:\\update.txt";
   String key=vars.get("name");
   String newname=file_name+key;
   File file=new File(newname);
   FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file);
   out.write(result);
   out.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have 10 concurrent downloads of the file which is more than 300 megabytes you will need at least 4 GB of heap space in order to fit everything (and looking into your "code" it would rather be around 10 GB), if it's not enough measure heap usage for 1 user and 2 users using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) and extrapolate it for 10 users
2. [Don't use Beanshell for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
3. If you need to save response to the local drive it's better to go for [Save Responses to a file listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file), check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) for more details if needed